# I want to grow in my din but having a lack of understanding

Tags: sunnah, non-muslim-countries, education

I'm american born muslim since i was a young boy. I find it hard to keep up with my din or feel like i'm not dong it right. I don't read arabic, i have trouble understanding or even keeping up with all the rules and sunnah. I feel like i'm a hypocrite because of my lack of understanding. To me i have no doubt about my belief but i feel like my prayers are not being done correctly. I read and try to educate myself on my din and find a alot of things that im either doing wrong or not enough of. Is this a sign that ALLAH has sealed my heart from Islam?

Comment: Read my friend, read. It takes effort, but all effort is worth it. If you want some personal advice on which books are suitable for you, I'm here.

Comment: Be aware that a good Muslim lives between hope and fear: hope for Allah's acceptance (of his deeds) and fear from Allah's punishment. Reading on specific topics might help and it is better to ask about thinks you are in doubt of, because doubt or any assumption doesn't lead to knowledge nor truth as Allah says: "And most of them follow not except assumption. Indeed, assumption avails not against the truth at all. Indeed, Allah is Knowing of what they do." (10:36)